# jQuery cross-domain request

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, http-options-method

I am using a javascript library which triggers jQuery-ajax post request to send a file to a specified rest url. This works perfectly on the same damain, but when I change it to another server it executes an OPTIONS request. Whats wrong?

Comment: read about CORS http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: Nothing's wrong ...that's how CORS works. OPTIONS is a preflight request to make sure the api is cors enabled before making the full request

Comment: one of the option is enable API for cross domain request if you have control over it or write a wrapper in between.

Comment: Schön, liefere jetzt generell ein Allow-Origin * aus. Das bekommt der OPTIONS call auch zurück. Und wie kann man den POST dann ausführen? Kann ich auf der jquery Antwort dann irgendwie sagen antwort.tuEndlichDasWasDuMachenSolltest!() ? ;)